# Read multiple data from client socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, java-io

Code for client which reads data from file and sends to server

```
public class Step2Client {
    public static void main( String args[ ] ) throws Exception
    {
        String ip="localhost";
        int port=9999;

        Socket s=new Socket(ip,port);
        String line="";
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        OutputStreamWriter os=new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(os);
        FileReader fileReader =new FileReader("input.txt");

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(line);
            System.out.print(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for server which has print data sent by client line by line:

```
public class Step2Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9999);
        Socket s=ss.accept();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        InputStreamReader inputStream=new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        String line = null;
        do {
            line = br.readLine ();
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        } while (line != null);
        System.out.print(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

But there is following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at Step2Server.main(Step2Server.java:20)
```

Comment: Do not forget to flush the output stream after writing and close the output stream and the socket after you are done at the client. The ServerSocket and Socket at the Server should be closed, too.

Comment: @fireandfuel Flush before close is redundant, as is closing the socket after closing one of its streams. He only needs to close the `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Your client isn't closing the socket, so when it exits the operating system is resetting it. It must be running on Windows. You should call `out.close()` after reaching the end of the input file.

NB Your read loop is incorrect. It should be:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
}
```

At present you are appending the final `null` to the `StringBuilder`.